# Replace an arbitraty select SQL with a count SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, replace

I need like to write a method (java) to transform an arbirtraty SQL string

```
select xxx,xxx,xxx 
from xxx
where xxxxx

-- or

select *
from xxx
where xxxxx
```

to a count sql string like:

```
select count(*) as total
from xxx
where xxxxx
```

I was thinking of replacing anything between `select` and `from` with `count(*) as total`, are there some potential problems with this approach? I don't need to handle EVERY case but I'd like to know which cases could be problematic with this approach and if I can afford to ignore them, or if you would do it some other way.

I cannot use this nested solution

```
select count(*)
from ( original query )
```

because of database sharding limitations.

Comment: you need to pay attention at least to `order by` and `group by` clauses, because replacing projection by `count(*)` makes SQL statement invalid if statement contains `order by` or `group by`. Another case is set operations: `UNION (ALL)`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS` - that is obvious you can't perform desired transformation. Why do not just enclose original query into `select count(*) from (...)`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov because the database sharding parsing engine will not allow nested queries that do not contain the sharding column, it won't know how to route the query and throw a parsing exception.

Comment: To do this properly you need a full SQL grammar (for the dbms you're using.)

Answer (score 1):

We can try a regex replacement here, targeting the `SELECT` clause.  Assuming that each part of the query be on a separate line, we can try:

```java
String sql = "select xxx,xxx,xxx \nfrom xxx\nwhere xxxxx";
String output = sql.replaceAll("\\bselect.*", "select count(*) as total");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
select count(*) as total
from xxx
where xxxxx
```

The regex pattern `\bselect.*` will match the `select` keyword until the end of that line (`.*` will not match across newlines by default).  We then replace with the desired select count.